# Average precision is not displaying right (scikit)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using the classification report of sklearn and this is the output:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1     0.5525    0.8118    0.6575     71194
      2     0.8782    0.1371    0.2372     13877
      3     0.5343    0.6083    0.5689     61591
      4     0.7953    0.3230    0.4594     13187
      5     0.6621    0.6701    0.6661     57530
      6     1.0000    0.0008    0.0017      2391
      7     0.6655    0.2095    0.3187     30223
```

avg / total     **0.6221**    0.5852    0.5566    249993

though when you do it manually you can see it is not right. [As can be seen here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%280.552452%20%2b%200.878173%20%2b0.534334%2b0.795331%2b0.662109%2b1.000000%2b0.665476%29/7)

Any idea why this is ?

With all the other reports of other algorithms, I do get a correct result. I suspect it has something to do with the precision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be caused by unbalanced classes. I think the total is not the average over classes but the total over all examples. So when the classes have different sizes, you have to take a weighted average to obtain the same result.

Comment: When computing precision / recall / f1-score using the `sklearn.metrics` functions on multiclass data you can select the averaging strategy (micro / macro / weighted). See the [docstrings](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) of those functions for more details.